# if('serviceWorker' in navigator) fails when loading site from search engines in iPhone, but fine loading directly in browsers & installs fine as a PWA

Tags: browser, service-worker

My website is loading fine when testing multiple browsers on Android and iPhone. However, it's not getting past...

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
```

when opening it's address:

https://www.songbookdb.com

...from a Google search in iPhone (iOS 16.5) - the browser that Google loads it into doesn't like it.

When I click the lock in the url window it shows the certificate is fine, so it's not an https issue.

It loads fine when clicking on the link in a Google search on my Android phone.

It also installs fine as a PWA on Android via Chrome, Firefox, and Edge and on iPhones via Safari, so I know the service worker is fine.

My default browser is Safari, but Google wants to load it into the browser with this button down the bottom center:

[image]

What browser is this please?

I just tested it in Yahoo's OneSearch and it's the same issue.

Comment: I removed if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {} (not a good idea) and it works, but links searched in Google and Yahoo on iPhone refuse to open in the default browser (Safari in my case) - they stay in their own weird part-of-the-search-app browser